# Looking for a Functional Form Satisfying Certain NonLinearites

Tags: functional-equations, nonlinear-optimization, economics, nonlinear-analysis

I'm working with a functional form

$\alpha = F(x,y,t)$ where t represents time and $x,y $ other factors affecting $\alpha$.

I want to find a functional form for F (that also has some parameters) such that

1)The treatment effect with respect to t is higher for medium values of y.

2)The treatment effect with respect to t is higher for medium values of x.

3)The treatment effect varies in a specific way for different values of x and y (e.g., highest for low x and low y, highest for medium x and medium y, and highest for high x and high y).

I need a function that is flexible enough to have these characteristics. I've tried Cobb-Douglass ($x^{\gamma_1}y^{-\gamma_2}z^{\gamma_3}$) and sigmoid form but haven't reached a satisfying function yet.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.